# Paypal Standard Checkout - What happens to a transaction that has been approved but not captured?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

In the Paypal Standard Checkout, there are 3 steps in the payment workflow:

1. Order Creation
2. Payment Approval
3. Payment Capture

What happens if somehow, the Payment Capture method is not called. Does the amount get deducted from the payer's bank account? If so, does it get returned to the payer's bank account if not captured within a specific period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If left in an approved status, nothing happens. Nothing at all.

Orders expire 72 hours after creation or 3 hours after a checkout loads.